# How to change the value of the current array key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to change all the values in a recursive array that will have an unknown number/depth of nested arrays. I think it's just syntax that I am tripping over.

Basically I need to output the $orgarray again with all new values.

```
$orgarray = array(
    '101' => 'some-value',
    '102' => 'some-value',
    '103' => 'some-value',
    '104' => array(
        '201' => 'some-value',
        '202' => 'some-value',
        '203' => array(
            '301' => 'some-value',
            '302' => array(
                '401' => 'some-value',
                '402' => 'some-value',
                    '501' => array(
                    '502' => 'some-value',
                    '503' => 'some-value',
                    '504' => 'some-value',
                    '505' => 'some-value',
                    '506' => 'some-vaslue'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    '105' => 'some-value',
    '106' => 'some-value',
    '107' => 'some-value'
);


function recursearray($array, &$modarray){

    foreach($array as $key => $value){

        if (is_array($value)){

            recursearray($value);
            // append keys to this nested array
                ???
        }else{

            // change current key's value
                ???

        }

    } 

}

recursearray($orgarray, $modarray);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($modarray);
echo '</pre>';
```

what am I doing wrong here?

1. I am unable to change the value of the current key
2. this won't output an array at all

*EDIT*
ok - I changed the way the function was being called:

```
function recursearray($array, &$modarray){
    if(!isset($modarray)) {
        $modarray = array();
    }

    foreach($array as $key => $value){

        if (is_array($value)){

            recursearray($value, &$modarray);
            // append keys to this nested array
            // neither of these work
            array_push($value['newkey'] = 'new_value');
            $value['newkey'] = 'new_value';


        }else{

            // change current key's value
            $array[$key] = 'value';

        }

    } 
    return $array;
}

$modarray = recursearray($orgarray, $modarray);
```

and now it's almost there, but I still don't understand why the original call to the function did not work ( recursearray($orgarray, $modarray); ) and the 2 methods trying to add keys to the nested arrays do not work either.

Comment: @Jack Are you not able to see the snippet of code he provided?

Comment: You want to change what how? What result do you expect?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst - What snippet of code? OP only provided a printout of an array.

Comment: @felix, basically I have an API function from a CMS that outputs   document ids in a handy array who's structure matched the site structure, but all it returns are the ids. I need to look up each id, get some information about it [doc name, uri etc] and update the org array with that info.

Comment: @jack - there is a bit of code under there.

Comment: So there is. Sorry for not scrolling down. Downvote reversed.

Comment: All you need is `$array[$key] = $new_value;`.

Comment: @felix, I know I tried that & it wasn't working, but it is now .. probably got side tracked by different problem.

Comment: actually this doesn't work either: $array[$key] = 'value'; can't change the value of something like $array[104][203][302]. I need to figure that out as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will works:

```
<?php    
function recursearray(&$array){
    foreach($array as $key => &$value){
       if (is_array($value)){
          recursearray($value);
       }else{
          $value = 'other-value';
       };
    };
};
?>
```

Take atention to `foreach($array as $key => &$value){`

Regards!